# Generate Apple RSS link within my app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to generate Apple RSS links dynamically, like what Apple does at [its site](http://itunes.apple.com/rss), but from within my app. Is there a framework for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate Apple RSS links" exactly? And what do you mean by "RSS links?" What exactly are you doing and where are you stuck? What code do you have? Also, while I'm asking questions, do you know what RSS is?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a httpserver and point the user to your server like `http://localhost:9999` and serve your RSS from there.

Something you can check out is [lighthttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) You can easily compile it into your app.